# Allow only my domain to serve images from my server

Tags: image, .htaccess, security, hotlinking

I know there are answered questions closely related to this one, but even after thorough research I have not found a solution that is applicable to my problem.

The problem is as follows: I have a file system that allows my users to upload a profile picture, and in the future an entire private gallery. I want to be able to, from one of my own pages, be able to fetch those profile pictures, say in the chatbox by simply adding `<img src="http://example.org/usercontent/[FOLDERID]/profilepicture.png" />`. At the same time I want to prevent people from entering http://example.org/usercontent/[FOLDERID]/profilepicture.png in their URL bar and just view the picure directly, because these pictures are supposed to only be visible to logged on users.
Is this possible? I have tried things like 
    `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example\.org/.*$ [NC]
     RewriteRule .(gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$ [R,NC,L]
     </ifModule>`

in my .htaccess file, but this results in all my images being blocked, even when I try `<img src="http://example.org/usercontent/[FOLDERID]/profilepicture.png" />`, which should just display the image, given that the image tag is written on one of my own pages.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to prevent people from entering `http://example.org/usercontent/[FOLDERID]/profilepicture.png` in their URL bar and just view the picure directly, because these pictures are supposed to only be visible to logged on users

You'll have to write a script that checks the user is logged in and returns the image file if so, eg using `readfile()` and suitable type and cache headers, or possibly mod_sendfile.

Referrer checking is neither secure nor reliable; it is not a workable authentication mechanism.

Comment: I don't understand. Doesn't `readfile` prompt a download? I just want to show the picture, not download it.

Comment: `readfile` just transfers a file to the browser. It's up to the browser to decide what to do with it. Typically it'll display it as an image if it's in an `<img>` element and it'll offer to save it if it's served with a `Content-Disposition: attachment` header.